# There is any way to make Visual Studio self hosted ASP.NET applications to receive external connections?

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio

I can't GET any of the pages hosted on my development machine externally, even after opening an exception at the Windows firewall.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Visual studio web server (aka Casini) won't accept remote connections - you need to use IIS.

Of course, I guess you could do something like run a program that proxies remote requests to it, but that's way more painful than just installing IIS on your dev machine and using that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the ASP.NET Debugging Server, it is not possible to access remotely. If you have Windows XP Professional or Vista with IIS, you can create a virtual directory that points to your publish folder.

If you are using IIS and you're behind a router, make sure you're forwarding port 80 traffic to your machine.